How to sum pandas columns across the same record for columns which begins with the same word
I have created the following pandas dataframe:
ds = {'col1' : [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4],
      'feature1' : [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4],
      'col2' : [12,3,4,5,4,3,2,3,4,6,7,8,3,3,65,4,3,2,32,1,2,3,4,5,32],
      
      }

df = pd.DataFrame(data=ds)

The dataframe looks like this:
print(df)
    col1  feature1  col2
0      1         1    12
1      1         1     3
2      1         1     4
3      1         1     5
4      1         1     4
5      1         1     3
6      1         1     2
7      2         2     3
8      2         2     4
9      2         2     6
10     2         2     7
11     3         3     8
12     3         3     3
13     3         3     3
14     3         3    65
15     3         3     4
16     4         4     3
17     4         4     2
18     4         4    32
19     4         4     1
20     4         4     2
21     4         4     3
22     4         4     4
23     4         4     5
24     4         4    32

I need to create a new column (called sumOfCols) which is the sum of the values contained in the columns whose names begin with col (in the example above the column feature1 would not be included in the calculation).
The resulting dataframe would look like this:

Can someone help me please?
Thanks in advance.

You can filter the columns using a regex, then sum on axis=1:
df["sumOfCols"] = df.filter(regex="^col").sum(axis=1)

    col1  feature1  col2  sumOfCols
0      1         1    12         13
1      1         1     3          4
2      1         1     4          5
3      1         1     5          6
4      1         1     4          5
5      1         1     3          4
6      1         1     2          3
7      2         2     3          5
8      2         2     4          6
9      2         2     6          8
10     2         2     7          9
11     3         3     8         11
12     3         3     3          6
13     3         3     3          6
14     3         3    65         68
15     3         3     4          7
16     4         4     3          7
17     4         4     2          6
18     4         4    32         36
19     4         4     1          5
20     4         4     2          6
21     4         4     3          7
22     4         4     4          8
23     4         4     5          9
24     4         4    32         36


Great!  Thank you very much

Just one more way to do it just in case you might not want to use RegEx or it to look a little more readable
columns_to_ignore = df.columns[~df.columns.str.startswith('col')].to_list()

df["sumOfCols"] = df.drop(columns=columns_to_ignore).sum(axis = 1)

This will dynamically get a list of all columns that don't start with 'col' then it will drop them from the summation aggregation along the column axis.

Another possible solution:
df.assign(sumOfCols = df[[col for col in df if col.startswith('col')]].sum(1))


Alternatively,
df['sumOfCols'] = df.loc[:,df.columns.str.startswith('col')].sum(1)


Output:
    col1  feature1  col2  sumOfCols
0      1         1    12         13
1      1         1     3          4
2      1         1     4          5
3      1         1     5          6
4      1         1     4          5
5      1         1     3          4
6      1         1     2          3
7      2         2     3          5
8      2         2     4          6
9      2         2     6          8
10     2         2     7          9
11     3         3     8         11
12     3         3     3          6
13     3         3     3          6
14     3         3    65         68
15     3         3     4          7
16     4         4     3          7
17     4         4     2          6
18     4         4    32         36
19     4         4     1          5
20     4         4     2          6
21     4         4     3          7
22     4         4     4          8
23     4         4     5          9
24     4         4    32         36

